# How to set Data cube config file?

Tags: data-cube

I'm trying to work on a new project and I red about Data Cube that can really help me.

In order to use it and to try to work with it, I installed postgres as required on the official website: https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/datacube-1.4.1/ops/db_setup.html

When trying to initialize the dataset with this command:

```
datacube -v system init
```

I get the error: "Error: No datacube config found"

As requested I added env var and tried to put the config file everywhere (home dir, default, current...)

config file:

```
[datacube]
db_database: datacube

# A blank host will use a local socket. Specify a hostname (such as localhost) to use TCP.
db_hostname:

# Credentials are optional: you might have other Postgres authentication configured.
# The default username otherwise is the current user id.
db_username: postgres 
db_password: postgres
```

I'm using windows 10 with conda, python 3.8,

Do you know what I'm missing?
TIA

Comment: sorry but what does this have to do with geopandas & rasterio? Those tags are for questions about those specific python libraries. If your question involves these *directly* in some way (not just "I'm trying to set up data-cube so I can store data I plan to eventually work with in geopandas"), then please explain how in your question, otherwise kindly edit the question to drop them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As provided in documentation -

> Datacube looks for a configuration file in ~/.datacube.conf or in the
> location specified by the DATACUBE_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.

Make sure you file name is datacube.conf and it is in the proper path